# Is it possible to use implode() as a condition ? If not, what's the best way to check if the array can be imploded?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array, implode

I want implode an array in a loop. Sometime this array is a simple array so it works, sometime that's a multidimensional array and my script throw an error.

Is it possible to do something like that :

```
if (implode($array) ) {

$builded = implode($array);

}
```

Exemple value for $array :

```
$array1 = ["cat", "dog"] ;

$array2 = [
    "cat",
    "dog",
    1 => ["wolf", "lion"]
] ;
$array3 = [
    "cat",
    "dog",
     1 => []
] ;
```

implode() only works on $array1, with array $2 and $3 implode() legitimately give me an error : `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Users[...]2_cms_php_functions\class_json.php on line 153`

I know that's possible with some function returning false like `if (file_get_contents($file))`. If not possible, what's the best way checking if an array can be imploded ?

I'm aware about `if (count($array) == count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE))` and others solutions checking if the array is multidimensional but that's not working with empty sub array (and I often got the case).

Comment: So you want to implode only if the array has no subarrays in it?

Comment: probably this solution of finding whether you have a multidimensional array will help? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-an-array-is-multidimensional-or-not-in-php/

Comment: @nice_dev yes implode can't work on multidimensional array I want prevent the error and make another treatment for multidimensional array.

Comment: @eugene-kapustin yes if there is no other solution, I will do this, but I want to know if there is another way !

Comment: @Camille When you say _that's not working with empty sub array_, can you show an example?

Comment: @nice_dev updated my question with example !

Comment: @Camille Makes sense now. So to conclude, if the array is more than 1 level deep, the custom function we make should return false for an implode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can write a simple function to check if the array is recursive or not. If it ain't , function returns true, else false indicating whether it can be imploded or not.

```
<?php

function canImplode($data){
    foreach($data as $val){
        if(is_object( $val ) || is_array( $val )) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if(canImplode($array)){
  $builded = implode($array);
}
```

Comment: Looks like the best solution, I'm a bit sad there is no way to catch condition like "if this function throw a warning or a notice" which would have been really useful ! Thanks anyway !

Comment: @Camille It does throw a notice however throwing an exception would have been much better to handle.